# scapy showing error with pypy

Tags: scapy, pypy

I've installed pypy and installed scapy for pypy. In pypy website scapy is listed as compatible module.
But when I tried this,

```
>>>> from scapy.all import *
>>>> sendp(Ether()/IP(dst='172.16.0.2'))
```

It gave an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/pypy-2.2.1/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 255, in sendp
    __gen_send(conf.L2socket(iface=iface, *args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count, verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "/usr/lib64/pypy-2.2.1/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 414, in __init__
    self.ins.bind((iface, type))
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
error: unknown address family
```

Then I googled it, and tried to do the same following [this link](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issue/1525/):

```
>>>> from scapy.layers.inet import IP, Ether
>>>> from scapy.sendrecv import sendp
>>>> sendp(IP(dst='172.16.0.2'))
```

I still get the exact same error. I thought may be with `sendp()` some error might be there. so I tried the exact code mentioned in that link:

```
>>>> from scapy.layers.inet import IP
>>>> from scapy.sendrecv import send
>>>> send(IP(dst='172.16.0.2'))
```

No doubt it's not a success, but the error message changes completely saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/pypy-2.2.1/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 247, in send
    __gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "/usr/lib64/pypy-2.2.1/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 230, in __gen_send
    s.send(p)
  File "/usr/lib64/pypy-2.2.1/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 372, in send
    iff,a,gw  = x.route()
  File "/usr/lib64/pypy-2.2.1/site-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 358, in route
    return conf.route.route(dst)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'route'
```

Can anybody help me how to work around scapy in pypy? I've my code in python which sniffs a packet from pcap file, modifies few fields in the packet and sends it. Which runs completely fine except the 10ms time it takes which is quite long. I thought of trying to make it less using pypy. But I can't find any solution to the above errors.

**Updated:** (After testing for address family)

I couldn't find a way to check with `pdb`. but I checked by taking other IP addresses:

`p=Ether()/IP(src='127.0.0.1', dst='172.16.0.2')` was showing `"unkown address family"` error for even `p.show()`.

But `p=Ether()/IP(src='127.0.0.1', dst='127.0.0.1')` is showing the packet details with `p.show()` but showing same error with `send()` or `sendp()`.

Comment: Some rare address families are supported in CPython but not in PyPy.  Can you check what address family it is trying to use in the first example?  (See the constructor of ``self.ins``)

Comment: @ArminRigo I'm not that much good in python. Can you tell me how to check that self.ins?

Comment: After you get the error in the interactive prompt, `import pdb;pdb.pm()` and `p self.ins`.  If it doesn't help, look at the source code.

Comment: @ArminRigo Updated the question. And I'm wondering loop back IP also not supported?

Comment: `pip install scapy` or `pip install --pre scapy` fails for me right now, in any version of CPython or PyPy, so I can't test.

Comment: @ArminRigo For me also it failed. (Even with python it fails.) So I downloaded the python package and installed using `pypy setup.py install`.

Comment: Added https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issue/1942/support-for-af_xxx-sockets .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in PyPy.  If this were a bug report I would close it. :-)

The closed bug report is https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issue/1090/cant-bind-packet-socket.

Comment: If this actually has been fixed, consider providing some evidence by linking to the closed bug report or the commit that fixes it.